# Degredation test of RAID 1

Tags: raid

I have just configured two hard drives with RAID1 via an ubuntu 10.4 installation. It is installed to boot in degraded mode.

I want to disconnect the power from the one drive and have it boot, and then put the power back and have it go back to original setup.

How do I do this?

The degredation test is simple, just remove the one hard drive, but then how do I put that removed hard drive back without having to do a full rebuild of the raid array?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: added the question

Answer (score 1):

You can accelerate the rebuild by enabling the write-intent bitmap:

```
sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --bitmap=internal
```